# java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ in Android retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit to consume a REST API endpoint, and I'm having the following issue.
I think the something is wrong with data model on TransactionResponse class, but not sure yet.

> java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ in
>   Android retrofit

My call request is as follows.

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/ifapi.php")
Call<TransactionResponse> loadData(@Field("user") TransactionRequest user);
```

TransactionRequest class :

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")

public class TransactionResponse {

    private Settings settings;
    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The settings
     */

    public Settings getSettings()
    {
        return settings;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param settings
     * The settings
     */

    public void setSettings(Settings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    private Actions actions;
    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The actions
     */
    public Actions getActions()
    {
        return actions;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param actions
     * The actions
     */
    public void setActions(Actions actions)
    {
        this.actions = actions;
    }
}
```

And below is the code where call is actually done.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl( 
RestAPI.BASE_URL).client(httpClient).build();
RestAPI service = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
Call<TransactionResponse> meResponse = service.loadData(request);

meResponse.enqueue(new Callback<TransactionResponse>() {
       @Override 
       public void onResponse(Call<TransactionResponse> call, Response<TransactionResponse> response) {
               if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                       TransactionResponse body = response.body();
                       Actions actions = body.getActions();
                       Map<String, String> params = actions.getParams();
               }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<TransactionResponse> call, Throwable t){
              t.printStackTrace();
       }
  });
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

I'm using the following libraries.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

P.S I found that the request worked with form data, but not with JSON data.
[image]

Comment: Look at this [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1691) on retrofit github. It says that your body length is 0

Comment: Thanks, I already knew that issue and that's why I want to find the issues on my data models.

Comment: I found the issue, you were right, the body was null since the call only worked with form requests. Can you help me to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, you need to post each parameters in the form as follows, not in a wrapper class.

```
@FormUrlEncoded

@POST("/ifapi.php")

Call<TransactionResponse> loadData(@Field("app_id") String app_id, @Field("install_id") String install_id, @Field("useragent") String useragent, @Field("ip") String ip, @Field("mccmnc") String mccmnc, @Field("action") String action );
```

And for main Activity Part.

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                                       .setLenient()
                                       .create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).baseUrl(RestAPI.BASE_URL).client(httpClient).build();

RestAPI service = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
Call<TransactionResponse> meResponse = service.loadData("1", getUUID(), getUserAgent(), getIPAddress(), "20404", "start");
```

Hope this will resolve your issues, Regards.

Comment: Worked like a charm, you saved my day! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When I used Coroutines what helped me was not returning anything from function call:

```kotlin
@GET
@Headers("X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest")
suspend fun functionCall(
    @Url url: String
)
```

Comment: Fixed the same problem I'm facing. Suddenly when use coroutines, my network call will always return an error. Removing return value fixed it, thanks! But do you have any idea why adding a return will cause the error?