# Retrofit with moshi throwing EOFException

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, moshi

In my project i am using Retrofit along side moshi to parse the json server responses.

I created a generic wrapper class for the server response

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class ResultsResponse<out T>(
    @field:Json(name = "data")
    val results: List<T>
)
```

and this is the class for the actual data of the json

```
@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Teacher(
    @field:Json(name = "id") override val id: Int,
    @field:Json(name = "profile") val profile: Profile?,
    @field:Json(name = "company") val company: Company?,
    @field:Json(name = "organization") val organization: Organization?
)
```

Which i use as the return value for each of the retrofit interface functions

```
@GET("teachers/{id}")
    suspend fun getTeacher(
        @Path("id") id: Int,
        @Query("include") relations: String = "",
        @QueryMap query: Map<String, String> = mapOf()
    ): Response<ResultResponse<Teacher>>
```

Most of the times the json is parsed ok but there are times that Moshi throws the following 
exception

```
W/System.err: java.io.EOFException: End of input
        at com.squareup.moshi.JsonUtf8Reader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonUtf8Reader.java:1057)
        at com.squareup.moshi.JsonUtf8Reader.doPeek(JsonUtf8Reader.java:252)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.JsonUtf8Reader.hasNext(JsonUtf8Reader.java:185)
        at com.adelve.findmyteacher.data.models.network_responses.ResultsResponseJsonAdapter.fromJson(ResultsResponseJsonAdapter.kt:35)
        at com.adelve.findmyteacher.data.models.network_responses.ResultsResponseJsonAdapter.fromJson(ResultsResponseJsonAdapter.kt:20)
        at com.squareup.moshi.internal.NullSafeJsonAdapter.fromJson(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:40)
        at com.squareup.moshi.JsonAdapter$2.fromJson(JsonAdapter.java:161)
        at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:45)
        at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiResponseBodyConverter.convert(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:227)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:142)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:140)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Is it possible that Moshi does not go well with the generic wrapper class i use and need to create a custom one? Or is the issue somewhere else. This exception occurs on average 4/10 network calls. I cant seem to find why this exception is being throw.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ in Android retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444871/java-io-eofexception-end-of-input-at-line-1-column-1-path-in-android-retrofit)